# User-uploaded images without an account

Tags: images

What are folks doing in the way of allowing users to upload images, but not have an account in order to perform the upload? So I'm user Bill, and I come to your website. You're having a contest for user-submitted work desk photos, and I want to submit my desk picture for the contest. You, site Owner Jane, don't want me to have an account in order to upload a photo.

Ignore any logical inconsistencies in the example please, the goal is image upload without site account.

In the past I've just used something like Flickr or other image repositories, and let users post images there, sucking them in from there. My client doesn't want to do that if they don't have to.

Note: I am NOT looking for a plugin recommendation explicitly--what I'm looking for is a method for allowing this, whether that's custom PHP code or something else.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? Why don't you try starting some code and then post it here for people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Gravity Forms for this very purpose, it took about 3 minutes to set it up.

The only difference in my case being that visitors were submitting a document rather than an image, but you just specify the allowable file types when creating the upload form field (e.g. jpg, png).

All the major form plugins provide file upload functionality (Ninja Forms, Contact Form 7, etc.).

You might have some coding to do depending on what you then want to do with the uploaded images.